# place a div into a fixed position woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress

CSS newbie here .

///
I'm facing some issues with one of my pages.

I can't fix the position of the price that is displaying.

tried absolute and clear both attributes.

The CSS is valid on 1920px width

*Guy Ytzhak solved my problem

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this? 
// can't fix the position of the price that is displaying//

Comment: Can you please tell us al the action within your 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' hook?

Comment: The price div is getting pushed up by the other components of the page. I want it to stay fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your functions.php file in your theme folder:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
```

it's remove the price from his position under the title in your single product page.

and than your can add this action whenever you want in your page by using this (it's only example):

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 35);
```

you can see that I remove the price from display in the priority 10(irst step) and than add him under the priority 35.

this is the regular priority in the woocommerce single product page:

```
/**
             * Hook: Woocommerce_single_product_summary.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
             */
```

and if your are using priority 35 its goes between 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart' and 'woocommerce_template_single_meta'.

Comment: This is my current code and div css : https://pastebin.com/3jkP5uAt but the price still gets pushed up  .

Comment: Remove the magin top minus in your css. and if you can send us the link to the webpage to see the problem in our eyes is helpfull